# Type defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Happens in only a single spot

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting the following error that seems really strange, and unsure how to fix it.

> The type 'IDataTransaction' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Project.Common.LLBL,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The code in question is this: (This code is defined in a `CategoryService.cs` inside `Project.Services.csproj`)

```
public CategoryHierarchyNode GetCategoryNavigationTree(int categoryID, UserContext userContext, bool includeObsolete = false)
{
    //This is where the error occurs.  If I comment out this line and return null, it compiles just fine.
    return _getCategoryNavigationForNodeComponent.Execute(categoryID, includeObsolete, userContext);
}
```

This is part of a service class that has many methods that make similar method calls to other components.

_getCategoryNavigationForNodeComponent is an interface defined as: (This interface is inside a `Project.BusinessLogic.csproj`)

```
public interface IGetCategoryNavigationForNodeComponent
{
    CategoryHierarchyNode Execute(int categoryID, UserContext userContext, IDataTransaction context);

    CategoryHierarchyNode Execute(int categoryID, UserContext userContext);

    CategoryHierarchyNode Execute(int categoryID, bool includeObsolete, UserContext userContext);

    CategoryHierarchyNode Execute(int categoryID, bool includeObsolete, UserContext userContext, IDataTransaction context);
}
```

Here is where I am confused.  According to the error message, I need to reference `Project.Common.LLBL`.  Strangely, if I comment out this line of code, everything compiles perfectly fine.  The other interfaces that reference the exact same `IDataTransaction` do not have this issue.  Is it SOLELY that one line of code that seems to fail, and I have no idea why.

In addition, if I remove the `includeObsolete` parameter from the `Execute` call, this seems to fix it as well, but I clearly want to keep that parameter.

What would cause this error to happen with only a specific interface?

**EDIT**

So in playing with the code, I tried adding named parameters to the Execute call, and now the error goes away:

```
public CategoryHierarchyNode GetCategoryNavigationTree(int categoryID, UserContext userContext, bool includeObsolete = false)
{
    return _getCategoryNavigationForNodeComponent.Execute(categoryID: categoryID, includeObsolete: includeObsolete, userContext:userContext);
}
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here?  My first thought is that the compiler is confusing the 3rd signature of the interface (which doesn't include the IDataTransaction parameter), and the 4th signature of the interface (which does include IDataTransaction).  Why would the compiler be confused about this?

Comment: Is IDataTransaction defined in multiple namespaces?

Comment: Nope, it is only defined in 'Project.Common.LLBL'

Comment: @EJoshuaS  Added an edit for some new findings, if you have an opinion on it.